# rspec vs bin/rspec: ignoring backtrace_cleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using RVM and I have `ruby-2.2.2` installed with the following gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (4.2.4)
rspec (3.3.0)
rspec-core (3.3.2)
rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
rspec-rails (3.3.3)
rspec-support (3.3.0)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
```

And now can anyone explain me why `bin/rspec` command ignores silencers defined in `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb` while `rspec` (which comes from `/home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec`) respects them?

```
# config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb

# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
# You can add backtrace silencers for libraries that you're using but don't wish to see in your backtraces.
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /rvm/ }
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /gems/ }

# You can also remove all the silencers if you're trying to debug a problem that might stem from framework code.
# Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
```

and here's output from `rspec` command (this is what I want)

```
Post
  is valid with title, body, published_at, status, author
  is valid without published_at
  is invalid without title
  is invalid with duplicated title (FAILED - 1)
  is invalid without body
  is invalid without status
  is invalid without author

Failures:

  1) Post is invalid with duplicated title
     Failure/Error: expect(post.errors[:title]).not_to include("has already been taken")
       expected ["has already been taken"] not to include "has already been taken"
     # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.46048 seconds (files took 2.55 seconds to load)
7 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:37 # Post is invalid with duplicated title
```

and here's output frm `bin/rspec` (why there are paths with `rvm`?):

```
[...]
Failures:

  1) Post is invalid with duplicated title
     Failure/Error: expect(post.errors[:title]).not_to include("has already been taken")
       expected ["has already been taken"] not to include "has already been taken"
     # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
     # /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
     # /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
     # /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
     # /home/dawid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.44223 seconds (files took 0.32406 seconds to load)
[...]
```

And yes, I have tried `/.rvm/` and `/\.rvm/` but that didn't change a thing. I'll use `rspec` instead of `bin/rspec` but i'm curious why that happens.

Comment: if you run `bundle exec bin/rspec` does it work correctly?

Comment: @Anthony nope, same results as `bin/rspec`